# deleting files in cordova does not result in extra disk space

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, diskspace

I have a cordova app that I use to record a video and than gets transcoded to a smaller size mp4. After it has been transcoded I delete the original, this all works fine.

For example, I have a 1GB recording that gets transcoded to a 190MB mp4 (lower resolution and bitrate) and after the deletion of the 1GB file, it really is gone as in i can't find it not when i scan the directory  where it used to be (cordova.file.dataDirectory) neither with the device explorer in android studio.

All is fine, except for the fact that the 1GB disk space that the original used to occupy is not being released. When checking the app size in android it shows that the data used by the app is still more than 1GB?
Only after a reboot of the phone is the disk space released.

Is there a way to trigger this release of disk space other than by rebooting the phone?
I am using cordova 9.0.0 and am deleting the files with the cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1

Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with this situation, but I do know that "operating systems are often 'lazy.'"  If you deleted the file, the operating system might perceive no need to steal the memory away from your application -- running operating-system level "garbage collection," so to speak.  If there's no pressure being exerted on the main-memory resource, from the operating system's perspective, "why bother?"  So, I think that what you're seeing here is actually of no consequence.

Comment: I think you are right, but it is of consequence to me because it sometime takes a very long time for the space to be really being freed. So long that the storage of the phone is actually full and i can't make another recording. So it would be nice if there was a way to activate the garbage collector

Comment: I found out what the problem is, the camera app seems to be the culprit. It looks like the camera app still has a reference to the file that keeps the system from releasing the disk space. When I force kill the app all the disk space that was missing is being freed. So the question now is how do I get the camera app to release the files from code?